# Running Socket Programming code in Eclipse

Tags: java, sockets

I have written a program on Socket Programming, and I created a client and a server. Codes for both are as follows:

CLIENT:

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class GreetingClient
 {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
      String serverName = args[0];
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

SERVER:

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class GreetingServer extends Thread
 {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
    {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
      serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    }

    public void run()
    {
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
            serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out =
                 new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
              + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
       }
     }
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      try
      {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Now, I am unable to run the program in Eclipse, can anyone help me, how to do this ?

Comment: In what way are you unable to run the program? What did you try? What did not work as expected? Any error messages?

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm unable to run` ? you don't know how to use eclipse? or is there some bug in your program?

Comment: I implemented a new project, and I made these two classes. Now, unable to run in the sense, I am not able to get, how to check whether the server, or the client is actually functioning. I know, I need to pass in some command line arguments, but what are they, and what I need to do, is still not understood.

Comment: so, do you click on something in eclipse and it doesn't do what you expect?  Or do you not know what to click on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, you need to run the programs individually in the
>   Eclipse-IDE. The output will be indented one on another in next tab on
>   the output area.

I don't have info about Eclipse.

> In Netbeans,you need to run the Client.java file separately. Then,move
>   to Server.java file and run it separately. You'll see at the bottom
>   that two windows---one running Client.java and the other running
>   Server.java will be running independently. Now,send message from
>   client to server and vice-versa.

EDIT FOR YOUR COMMAND LINE PARAMETER SETTING IN ECLIPSE IDE :-

Go to Project--> Run --> Run Configurations --> Arguments.!

Pass the arguments as

args[0]=127.0.0.1   //local-host

args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQWmF.png)=3000      //say 3000,you can give any port no. but take care that it should exist!

[image: Parameter passing]

Comment: When i run this in Eclipse, I get an error saying 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArratIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0'. I know, I am unable to pass the arguments in Eclipse, that is why this error is turning up, so can you please tell the solution to this?

Comment: Man,for that you need to set up passing argument in Eclipse.It's a different procedure.

Comment: I did pass in the arguments, but what to pass, is what I am not getting. Pretty new to programming, you see. can you help by getting a gist of the program, what all needs to be written in the command prompt?

Comment: @user3676294-Did you simply copy the code? That's pretty bad. Think for yourself,if you'll not get it then I'll answer it.

Comment: @user3676294-Updated the code for you,run it and tell me now whether it runs perfectly!

Comment: Your program is aspecting port no. as argument. You can give any free post no. e.g. 4545,7070. User same port no. for both server and client.

Comment: @user3676294-Kindly accept the solution if satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `RunConfigurations..` and click on the Class Name(as here '`GreetingClient`') under the java application in the left pane of RunConfiguration window

on the right side you will get many tab like `Main`,`Arguments`,`jre`,`ClassPath` etc so now click on the '`Arguments`'
below this tag you will get textbox with label `Program arguments:` 
here in this textbox you need to pass your command line argument

for multiple values give `single space` between the `argument values` then click on the `Apply` button

like in above case you need to pass commandline argument twice.
so first you configure for the `GreetingServer`  and then for the `GreetingClient` and then `apply` and `run` one by one

click on the `GreetingServer.java` and then right click on mouse and select `Run As-->Run Configuration..` then go to `Java Application` and click

```
GreetingServer -->Argument--> 6000   -->apply and -->run
```

output like this

```
Waiting for client on port 6000...
```

now click on the `GreetingClient.java` and then right click on mouse and select `Run As-->Run Configuration..` then go to `Java Application` and click

```
GreetingClient -->Argument--> 127.0.0.1 6000   -->apply and -->run
```

then you will get your application running and 
output like this

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 6000
Just connected to /127.0.0.1:6000
Server says Thank you for connecting to /127.0.0.1:6000
Goodbye!
```

Any port you can send it your wise just keep in mind port no. should be free
for the eclipse argument passing you can go through this [link](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html#ARGS)

Answer (score -1):

Try running the Client program first and then run the server program in Netbeans, the program will run with no problem...

Answer (score -1):

```
/*Server*/    
import java.net.*;        
import java.io.*;        
public class MyServer 
{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(8100);
    Socket s=ss.accept();
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str="",str2="";
    while(!str.equals("stop"))
    {
    str=din.readUTF();
    System.out.println("clint Says"+str);
    str2=br.readLine();
    dout.writeUTF(str2);
    dout.flush();
    }
    din.close();
    s.close();
    ss.close();
    }
}
```